# pandas add a ranking column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                   'importance':[0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8]})

df
  feature  importance
0       a         0.1
1       b         0.5
2       c         0.4
3       d         0.2
4       e         0.8
```

I want to add a column `ranking`, that assigns rank to each feature by evaluating:

```
feature_rank = feature's importance/sum of all features importance
```

So feature that:

```
a -> 0.1 /(0.1 + 0.5 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.8) = 0.05
b -> 0.5 /(0.1 + 0.5 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.8) = 0.25
c -> 0.4 /(0.1 + 0.5 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.8) = 0.2
d -> 0.2 /(0.1 + 0.5 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.8) = 0.1
e -> 0.8 /(0.1 + 0.5 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.8) = 0.4
```

**Expected results:**

The final `df` will therefore be:

```py
  feature  importance    ranking
0       a         0.1      5
1       b         0.5      2
2       c         0.4      3
3       d         0.2      4
4       e         0.8      1
```

Comment: `df['importance'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)`. Divide by a constant is irrelevant here (with your sample).

Comment: @arthurq it depends if there can be negative numbers, but yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) after normalizing with the Series' [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['ranking'] = (df['importance'].div(df['importance'].sum())
                 .rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                 .astype(int) # optional
                )
```

Note that dividing by a strictly positive integer won't change the rank, so if the sum is positive, you can simplify to:

```
df['ranking'] = df['importance'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
  feature  importance  ranking
0       a         0.1        5
1       b         0.5        2
2       c         0.4        3
3       d         0.2        4
4       e         0.8        1
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not seem very efficient, but this is just another way of achieveing the same problem.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                   'importance':[0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8]})
df = df.sort_values(by='importance', ascending=False)
df["rating"] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df = df.sort_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.assign(ranking = df.sort_values('importance', ascending=False).index + 1)
```

Output:

```
  feature  importance  ranking
0       a         0.1        5
1       b         0.5        2
2       c         0.4        3
3       d         0.2        4
4       e         0.8        1
```